# Oracle SQL alter table add column with current user name

Tags: sql, oracle

It was a 2 part question and I got the timestamp correctly.
I'm on 12C and trying to do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD modified_by (USER FROM DUAL);
```

Basically just columns in a table that show who modified the table and at what time they did so.

I also tried

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD last_modified TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD modified_by USER;
```

and other combinations of keywords that I found on this site and other sites but none of them work.

We only learned dual in class but I'm looking for any way to do these.

Edit:

I now understand what was taught to me by the user with almost 1 million points.

Still unsure how to do the username.
Read this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2114.htm#REFRN20302

and tried:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD modified_by USERNAME;
```

doesn't work get invalid datatype.

Then saw this: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/find_users.php

and tried:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD modified_by USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS;
```

but getting invalid alter table option.  SQL is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you edited the question, it seems that you are somewhat closer to what you want. This:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD modified_by VARCHAR2(30);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                      datatype goes here, not what you'd like
                                      to put into this column
```

Then, during inserts or updates of that table, you'd put `USER` in there, e.g.

```
insert into customers (id, modified_by) values (100, USER);
```

---

Or, probably even better, set it to be default, as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD modified_by VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT USER;
```

so - if you don't explicitly put anything into that column, it'll be populated with the `USER` function's value.

Comment: I think mlstudent is trying to do the equivalent of `ADD modified_by varchar2(30) DEFAULT USER;`

Comment: I think you might be right, @a_horse. Thank you, I added it above.

Comment: This is what I ended up with `ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD modified_by varchar(30) default USER;`  That's great to have confirmation from pros.

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the Oracle [documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) on virtual columns, you will find this:

> Functions in expressions must be deterministic at the time of table creation, but can subsequently be recompiled and made non-deterministic

A deterministic function is one that returns the same value when it is passed the same arguments.  The expressions that you are using contain non-deterministic functions.  Hence, they are not allowed.

The error that I get when I try this is:

> ORA-54002: only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression

For some unknown reason, Oracle equates "pure" with "deterministic" in the error message.  But this is saying that the function needs to be deterministic.